# JFrame gets locked completely while method is running

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe

I have a GUI(JFrame), with two Buttons and 1 Panel to show the result. One Button is to start the algorithm, one for stopping it. By pressing start, a method is called and it starts running. The runtime of this method varies from couple of seconds to 2-3 minutes, depending on the input.

The problem I have hereby is, by pressing the start-button, the GUI gets completely locked. I cannot press any button till the algorithm terminates. It would be great to be able to stop the algorithm and to visualize parts of the solution after a certain amound of time.

I checked every single line of the Frame, there is nothing that disables it.

//If needed I can provide code, but its pretty long and just some hints and reasons for the problem would be great and I try to fix it by myself.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put long-running tasks on the EDT, or the Event Dispatching Thread. Use threading or a SwingWorker instead. Hopefully that's enough google keywords to get you started. :)

Comment: SwingWorker was the magic word. Fixed the problem in 20minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your algorithm is running in the same thread as the UI components. You probably want to read up on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to better understand how to create threads, monitor execution, integrating these concepts with a Swing-based user interface, and so forth. At a very high level, you are going to need to somehow spawn a new thread when your algorithm starts and observe it for intermediate state changes to update the UI. You only want user interface related code running in the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).